# Is the incorrect to use margins on the majority of your html object to arrange them?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, margins

sorry about asking a question like this but I am just getting the hang on Dreamweaver and using margins seems harmless at the start but once I progressed in building my page objects seem to be out of place, is there something i can do to help with this?

Comment: Can u b more specific

Comment: Please show us your code so we can provide you with some real answers. Generic, almost vague questions will get you nowhere :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using margins everywhere will cause a problem when you resize your browser or check your website on a smaller screen.

You can check this website [learnlayout.com](http://learnlayout.com) to learn the basics of div based layouts.

Comment: Yes, @user3094582, you may want to check out responsive design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Thats great to hear. Cheers!